# JavaFX TabPane disable tab switching by keys

Tags: java, javafx, keylistener, eventhandler

I have a `Tab` with some content: `ScrollBar` and other.

The `ScrollBar` has event handler for keys: <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd>.

But if I press these buttons, `Tabs` are switched, because `TabPane` also has a  key handler.

How to disable default event handler for `TabPane` or change switching policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `ScrollBar` is not [focus traversable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty--) by default and key events are only fired for focused `Node`s.

You can set the `ScrollBar` focus traversable:

```
sb.setFocusTraversable(true);

sb.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if ( e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.RIGHT))
        sb.setValue(sb.getValue()+0.01);
    else if(e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.LEFT))
        sb.setValue(sb.getValue()-0.01);
});
```

In this case whenever the `ScrollBar` is focused, the key events are handled.

Comment: But also how we can disable Left and Right Arros for TabPane completely.